# Consuming NetSuite SOAP Webservice in .Net Core

Tags: soap, .net-core, netsuite

I am having a bit of an issue with integrating with NetSuite API on .Net Core using VS2017 and it has no option to add Web Service. When I consumed their web service using add connected services some objects and classes are missing. 
In .Net 4.5, the classes and object are available. My manager wants me to write the API in .Net Core.

I took the [sample code](http://www.netsuite.co.uk/portal/uk/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml) from NetSuite and the very first thing is class NetSuiteService which has important Passport property for login.

Anyone had a solution to this?

Comment: could you consume suitetalk from net core?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to integrate SuiteTalk with Dot NetCore, all you need to do is import the WSDL into .NetCore project via adding it as ConnectedService reference and it will set you up with WCF.
The DEMO code that NetSuite people have provided will not match the code generated on your machine. I would recommend you using TBA instead of other authentications. 
(just copy paste the code provided by NetSuite's folks for authentication as that is the convention, you can change the crypt algorithm if you want to, just generate the Keys, put them in your configs and you're good to go)

Class "`NetSuitePortTypeClient`" will contain your endpoints for all types of communication to NetSuite web services.
Read the first 50-100 pages of the documentation manual that NetSuite provides for learning the conventions to be used throughout your journey.
Hope this will give you a headstart.