# Initializing NetSuite client with NetSuitePortTypeClient

Tags: c#, wcf, netsuite

I am using NetSuite SOAP web service generated with WCF service reference. Generated file does not contain same classes as explained on their website.

Does anyone have a proper solution how to initialize client for using the web service?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a WCF service reference generated in Visual Studio. Have you tried to use the WCF client like described here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-use-a-wcf-client

Answer (score 1):

For calling a WCF service, I advise you follow the below way,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
In a project based on the Dotnet framework, there generally is an `Adding Service Reference` tool used for generating a client proxy. By means of that, we could call the remote service like the local method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    var result = client.Test();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Also, it generates some settings of the remote WCF service, located in the Appconfig/Webconfig file, please pay attention to change the default service address.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.69:21011/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! This is actually common problem in terms that generating Netsuite.wsdl as WCF service reference instead of web reference will have different classes for initializing the client. As it can be seen here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612490/consuming-netsuite-soap-webservice-in-net-core/53664961) . 
I am having problems with that. Btw I am using .net core.

Comment: If in a DotNet Framwork project, can you normally consume remote services? If possible, please post the client configuration file just like the above configuration in the Appconfig/webconfig. I’m not familiar with this class library, but if you are in a DotNet Core project, you may not be able to call traditional SOAP services properly, which has some compatibility issues. Besides, please refer to the below link to call the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide